# Import the .h of main project into pods project

Tags: ios, objective-c

How can I access the Main project's file from the Pods class? I did some research and found that I have to add a class file into the Header of the Build Phases but that also didn't help.

Comment: What are you trying to do? This is using your own framework or a third-party one?

Comment: Minor grammar cleanup.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider extracting the class(es) you would like to reference/reuse as a separate Pod/library. That way you can cleanly/safely refer to it from a Pod and your main codebase. It may not be what you want to hear but it's the best approach and will age better.

Comment: Well i am not much familiar with the pods, Can you explain what you mean by extracting the classes? does it mean that i have to create a class which ultimately refers to the classes of pods?

Comment: Hey, if I understand, you want to refer to code in your app from a Pod. That isn't easily possible because your app isn't a framework. If you take some of the core logic that you'd like to refer to in the Pod you're working on, call it PodA and extract it into another Pod (PodB), then it works. It sounds like a lot of work perhaps, but your code will be more modular and reusable as a side benefit.